# On user selection, set product price to 0 for cart, checkout in shopify

Tags: shopify, product

I am facing a issue in shopify. The issue is I am listing products on a page with price. But i want whatever first 3 products customer click should be free for them. The fourth one they click should be of price set on backend.
So basically all products will have price. But first 3 client select should be free for them. Is this customization possible in shopify?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. One, you use Shopify Plus, and with that you are free to script the checkout and change prices to free on items in the checkout. Or two, without Plus, you are free to use Discount Codes to bring the price of a checkout down to zero for items that meet criteria you setup. Those are your only sane choices at this time.